# Problems with creating a CUDA shared library and libpthread

Tags: gcc, linker, cuda, pthreads, ld

I am currently trying to create a library with CUDA routines but I am running into trouble. I will explain my problems using a rather minimal example, my actual library will be larger.

I have successfully written `test.cu`, a source file containing a `__global__`  CUDA function and a wrapper around it (to allocate and copy memory). I can also successfully compile this file into a shared library using the following commands:

```
nvcc -c test.cu -o test.o -lpthread -lrt -lcuda -lcudart -Xcompiler -fPIC
gcc -m64 -shared -fPIC -o libtest.so test.o -lpthread -lrt -lcuda -lcudart -L/opt/cuda/lib64
```

The resulting `libtest.so` exports all my needed symbols.

I now compile my purely C `main.c` and link it against my library:

```
gcc -std=c99 main.c -o main -lpthread -ltest -L.
```

This step is also successful, but upon executing `./main` all CUDA functions that are called return an error:

```
test.cu:17:cError(): cudaGetDeviceCount: [38] no CUDA-capable device is detected
test.cu:17:cError(): cudaMalloc: [38] no CUDA-capable device is detected
test.cu:17:cError(): cudaMemcpy: [38] no CUDA-capable device is detected
test.cu:17:cError(): cudaMemcpy: [38] no CUDA-capable device is detected
test.cu:17:cError(): cudaFree: [38] no CUDA-capable device is detected
```

(Error messages are created through a debugging function of my own)

During my initial steps I encountered the exact same problem, as I was directly creating an executable from `test.cu`, because I forgot to link against libpthread (`-lpthread`). But, as you can see above, I have linked all source files against libpthread. According to `ldd`, both `libtest.so` and `main` depend on libpthread, as it should be.

I am using CUDA 5 (yes, I do realize it is a beta) with gcc 4.6.3 and nvidia driver version 302.06.03 on ArchLinux.

Some help in solving this problem would be more than appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure this isn't just a thread affinity problem? Whichever thread creates/holds the context on the device is the only one which can use the device. If you want multiple threads to use the context, you will need to use the context migration API.

Comment: As I am not forking or anything, there should only be a single thread, if I am not vastly mistaken.

Comment: Sorry for asking the obvious, but do you have a CUDA capable device? And have you checked that other CUDA code works ok with the same toolkit/driver?

Comment: @Tom: No worries :-) Yes, I do have a CUDA capable device. Other CUDA code works perfectly. I also tested compiling my test code together with the main function into a single executable, which also works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a trivial example...

```
// File: test.cu
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void myk(void)
{
    printf("Hello from thread %d block %d\n", threadIdx.x, blockIdx.x);
}

extern "C"
void entry(void)
{
    myk<<<1,1>>>();
    printf("CUDA status: %d\n", cudaDeviceSynchronize());
}
```

Compile/link with `nvcc -m64 -arch=sm_20 -o libtest.so --shared -Xcompiler -fPIC test.cu`.

```
// File: main.c
#include <stdio.h>

void entry(void);

int main(void)
{
    entry();
}
```

Compile/link with `gcc -std=c99 -o main -L. -ltest main.c`.

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't work. Nothing is printed on stdout. I also augmented the `entry()` function to print the return value of `cudaDeviceSynchronize()`, which is the same as in my own example (38), meaning that no CUDA-capable device can be found.

Comment: BTW my example assumes you have a Fermi device or newer - device printf is not supported on older devices. If your device is Fermi or Kepler, then if other CUDA code works then there's no reason this shouldn't. You're using an unsupported distro/GCC so maybe there's something weird with the libs or linking step but not sure what. Can you try an older GCC or a different distro?

Comment: I have a Fermi device (GeForce 560 Ti, GF114). Testing with another distribution will be a little difficult, but I will install gcc 4.5 now and test again.

Comment: I found my mistake, which actually was incredibly stupid:

I had installed both gcc 4.7 and 4.6 in parallel and had created a symlink from `/opt/cuda/bin/gcc` to `/usr/bin/gcc-4.6`, so that `nvcc` uses gcc 4.6.
But what I missed was this: `nvcc` not only uses `gcc`, but also `g++`, for which I had not created such a symlink. Normally, if you use gcc 4.7 and try to compile CUDA code with `nvcc` you get an error message telling you about the incompatible compiler, but apparently `nvcc` only checks the compatibility of `gcc`, not also `g++`...

The above code now works with both gcc 4.5 and 4.6